# FileSystemWatcher memory leak even after Finalizer has run

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

Registering for an event on `FileSystemWatcher` causes the registering class to stay in memory even after eliminating all (my) references to the `FileSystemWatcher` and letting the GC and finalizers run. I've constructed an example below showing how an object using `FileSystemWatcher` stays in memory while another set of objects (of type `A` and `B`) which use similar events/eventhandlers do not stay in memory.

**Example**

```
class Program
{
    class UsesFileWatcher
    {
        public FileSystemWatcher fw;

        public UsesFileWatcher()
        {
            fw = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\", "*.txt");
            fw.Changed += eventHandler;
            fw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }

        void eventHandler(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }

    // For Comparison, I have classes A and B which use similar events and event handlers
    class A
    {
        public event EventHandler AEvent;
    }

    class B
    {
        public A a;

        public B()
        {
            a = new A();
            a.AEvent += eventHandler;
        }

        void eventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var weakRefToB = WeakReferenceToB();
        var weakRefToUsesFileWatcher = WeakReferenceToUsesFileWatcher();

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        Console.WriteLine("B Alive = {0}", weakRefToB.IsAlive);
        Console.WriteLine("UsesFileWatcher Alive = {0}", weakRefToUsesFileWatcher.IsAlive);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static WeakReference WeakReferenceToB()
    {
        return new WeakReference(new B());
    }

    static WeakReference WeakReferenceToUsesFileWatcher()
    {
        return new WeakReference(new UsesFileWatcher());
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

- I understand that FileSystemWatcher implements `IDisposable` and that I should be calling `Dispose()` when I'm done with it.  But my understanding is that if I miss the call to `Dispose()` that it just means that the work it needed to do would be done later during the finalizer.
- There is a known FileSystemWatcher memory leak documented [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2628838).  But the description sounds different than what I'm describing.
- I used Red Gate's ANTS Memory Profiler to show what is keeping it alive:
  [image: Image showing what is keeping UsesFileWatcher object alive]

**Question:**

Is this a bug in `FileSystemWatcher` or are my expectations incorrect somehow?

Comment: Nice question. I would like to get some professional answer in this too. My assumption would be the finaliser code has to remove the reference to the event or else it can't clean up

Comment: Usually the rule of thumb that I use is if I programically add a handler using += I remove it when I am done by using -=. I don't see you doing that here.

Answer (score -1):

Of course it's not a bug.  You can see right in the profiler that the object is being referenced.  There's a system type that is rooted that has a callback tot he FSW, making it accessible from a rooted object.

It will remove those callbacks when it is disposed of, enabling it to be collected, so you'll need to dispose it if you want it to be eligible for collection.